# Pushing user to particular view controller when a certain universal link is called in SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently attempting to push a user to a 'Callback' view controller when the user accesses a universal link ending in /callback. The app successfully opens when the link is called, but it just displays a blank black screen.

Here's the function in question:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
           // the url is going to be in userActivity.webpageURL
        print(userActivity.webpageURL)
        print(userActivity.webpageURL?.lastPathComponent)
        
        if (userActivity.webpageURL?.lastPathComponent == "callback") {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            self.window?.rootViewController = CallbackViewController()
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

I don't necessarily want it to be the 'rootViewController' though, I just want to navigate to it. I couldn't get the universal links to work in App Delegate, and it seems this now needs to be handled in Scene Delegate. Is this right? Is there a way to just push the user to the CallbackViewController instead of making it the root VC?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is basically the right idea except that you seem to have forgotten to make a window connected to the window scene.

```
guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
```

As for "just push the user to the CallbackViewController instead of making it the root VC", the app is launching so how you want to configure the overall view hierarchy is entirely up to you.